# Highlight DIV and dim the rest on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a page full of DIVs which contain images.

When I mouse over an image I can highlight it or add a shadow to accent it easily by adding class etc but is there a way to dim every other image instead.

DIVs are loaded into DOM and I would like the DIV currently hovered over to retain 100% or 1 opacity and the rest of the DIVs on the page to fade to say 70% or 0.7 when one DIV is highlighted.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('div').hover(function() {
    $('div').css({opacity: '0.7'});
    $(this).css({opacity: '1'});
}, function() {
    $('div').css({opacity: '1'})}
);
```

I think this should work.

Comment: Looks like should work but doesn't, I'm trying:

$('.divName').hover(function() {
    $('.divName').css({opacity: '0.7'});
    $(this).css({opacity: '1'});
}, function() {
    $('.divName').css({opacity: '1'})}
);

Comment: Works great, wrapped in doc.ready and not win.load - many thanks

Comment: No worries glad to have helped.

Answer (score 8):

**CSS only:**

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/umacat/183/edit)**

```
#parent:hover > div{ opacity:0.6; }    /* Fade ALL OUT on parent hover */   
#parent > div:hover{ opacity:1; }      /* Fade in hovered one */
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution. Initially I was trying a jQuery class updating solution, but that was surprisingly laggy and sometimes unreliable. This is perfect.

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is use a new div as a 'mask'.

You'd have your **image div**, with `z-index:1;` for example.

And you also have **another div** with `opacity:50%; position:fixed; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%; z-index:2;`. This black div has to be hidden when the page loads (`display:none;`).

Using javascript, when you mouseover the image div, the white div should change to `z-index:3;`, and the black div should change to `display:block;` or similar.

ADDENDUM:

If you don't want an overlay div, but only want to make the other images opaque, the javascript just needs to change the opacity (you can manage these opacities in classes, and then just use JS to switch between them).

Comment: That highlights the mouseover div though, no? and keeps all other DIVS darker or dimmed, not the right answer

Comment: Edited. I see you really enjoy asking questions, are you always this thankful with answers?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is probably:

1) Make a translucent overlay that covers the whole page.

2) Clone your DIV and position it on top of the overlay.